# How to create Asynchronous Tornado HTTP Server?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, couchbase

I have written the following HTTP Redirecting Server. During test I realized that it making call in a blocking manner, majorly because of syncronous call to couchbase. How can I run parallel request-response on a given socket? Should I implenebt asyncronous which a call is made to db?

```
class ABC(web.RequestHandler):

        def get(self):
                self.MartiniTagKey = self.get_argument("mtag", strip=True) #TEST1
                self.couchbase_start_time = time.time()
                couchbase_query_result = bucket.get(self.MartiniTagKey) #TEST2
                self.CouchbaseMS = time.time() - self.couchbase_start_time
                url_to_redirect = json.loads(couchbase_query_result[2])['metaTag'] #TEST3
                self.redirect(url_to_redirect)  



if __name__=="__main__":
        options.options.log_file_prefix = log_directory
        options.parse_command_line()
        db=MySQLdb.connect(host=mysql_host, user=mysql_user,
        passwd=mysql_password, port=int(mysql_port), db=mysql_db)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        couchbase = Couchbase(couchbase_host+':'+couchbase_port, couchbase_bucket, couchbase_password)
        process.fork_processes(0)
        bucket = couchbase[couchbase_bucket]
        app = web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", ABC),])
        app.listen(8080,"")
        io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        io_loop.start()
```

Comment: Currently there's a new Python SDK in the works at https://github.com/couchbaselabs/pylibcouchbase It's still synchronous, but it's planned to make it async. You're welcome to help out making it async :)

Comment: If you want asynchronous driver to couchbase, check https://github.com/facebook/tornado/wiki/Links.

Comment: it doesnt have a link for couchbase xP

Comment: you can also have your get start a new thread, and then no matter what it does will be non-blocking from Tornado's perspective - use a callback and the @async decorator